# How to create animated progress bar on form fil up in PHP Codeingiter

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap-3

for a registration form i want to set up Boostrap animated Progress bar. So as the user fills up the information the progress bar should increase dynamically! maybe this is very easy but i dont know how to do this dynamically in PHP Codeigiter!

Below is my Form :

```
    <h3><?php echo empty($user->id) ? '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> Add a Reseller' : 'Edit User ' . $user->name; ?></h3>
    <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
    <?php echo form_open(); ?>
    <table class="table">

        <tr>
            <td>SIP Username</td>
            <td><?php echo form_input('sip_username', set_value('sip_username', $user->sip_username)); ?></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>SIP Password</td>
            <td><?php echo form_input('sip_password', set_value('sip_password', $user->sip_password)); ?></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Key</td>
            <td><?php echo form_input('key', set_value('key', $user->key), 'readonly'); ?></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Allocation Block</td>
            <td><?php echo form_input('allocation_block', set_value('allocation_block', $user->allocation_block)); ?></td>
        </tr>


        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td><?php echo form_input('name', set_value('name', $user->name)); ?></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Reseller Email</td>
            <td><?php echo form_input('email', set_value('email', $user->email)); ?></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Password</td>
            <td><?php echo form_password('password'); ?></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Confirm password</td>
            <td><?php echo form_password('password_confirm'); ?></td>
        </tr>


        <tr>
            <td>User_Required</td>
            <td><?php echo form_input('user_num', set_value('user_num', $user->user_num)); ?></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Balance</td>
            <td><?php echo form_input('balance', set_value('balance', $user->balance),'id'); ?></td>
        </tr>


        <tr>
            <td>Phone</td>
            <td><?php echo form_input('phone', set_value('phone', $user->phone)); ?></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Address</td>
            <td><?php echo form_input('address', set_value('address', $user->address)); ?></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Status</td>
            <td><?php echo form_dropdown('status', array('Active' => 'Active', 'Inactive' => 'inactive', 'Delete' => 'delete'), $this->input->post('status') ? $this->input->post('status') : $user->status ); ?></td>  
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Country</td>
            <td><?php echo form_input('country', set_value('country', $user->country)); ?></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Country Code</td>
            <td><?php echo form_input('country_code', set_value('country_code', $user->country_code)); ?></td>
        </tr>




        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Save', 'class="btn btn-primary"'); ?></td>
        </tr>


    </table>
    <?php echo form_close();?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can write a jquery function for that like this. call the function on mouseout event

```
var fields = ["name, phone", "compname", "mail", "compphone", "adres", "zip"] // add all the field names in this array.
var empty = 0;
  var i, l = fields.length;
  var fieldname;
  for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    fieldname = fields[i];
    if (document.forms["register"][fieldname].value === "") {
      empty++;
   }
  }  

var percentage = (empty/l)*100;

// assign the percentage to your progress bar

$("#progess-bar").width(percentage);
```

Make sure you check the syntax errors.

Comment: i think var percentage should be
var percentage = ((empty-l)/l) * 100;

Comment: where should i write this function? In my controller or my view file?

Comment: <div class="progress progress-striped active">
  <div class="progress-bar" style="width: 70%"></div>
</div>

Comment: see this is static which changes as 70% but can increase it dynamically as the user fill us the details

Comment: @Rajan, didn't used it, but you could try to remove style attribute, or to update it (if style attribute is mandatory for some reason). Place provided code in your view file, and test it...You can get/set attribute value with attr() method: http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: what should i write in style="width...??

Comment: you should write the function in view. its a jquery function. 
$("#progress-bar").css(width:percentage+"%");
Try that

Answer (score 1):

You can refer the link below.

[Link](http://www.formget.com/displaying-progress-bar-on-form-submission-using-jquery/)

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
$("#submit").click(function() {
// To Display progress bar
$("#loading").show();
var name = $("#name").val();
var email = $("#email").val();
var mobile = $("#mobile").val();
var address = $("#address").val();
// Transfering form information to different page without page refresh
$.post("processing.php", {
name: name,
email: email,
mobile: mobile,
address: address
}, function(status) {
$("#loading").hide(); // To Hide progress bar
alert(status);
});
});
});
```

Comment: do i have to write this in my controller or should i write it in my view?

Comment: this tutorial does the progress bar thing after i submit the form! is it not possible that when i fill up the information the progress bar shows how much info is filled in!

Comment: <div class="progress progress-striped active">
  <div class="progress-bar" style="width: 70%"></div>
</div>

Comment: see the above set progress bar statically to 70%. can i change it dynamically?